# Concatenation of string in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this snippet

```
<script>
function redirect($i){
  $(function(){
    var trans = $('#trans'+$i).html();
    var mileage = $('#mileage'+$i).html();
    var eng = $('#eng'+$i).html();
    var ext = $('#ext'+$i).html();
    var stock = $('#stock'+$i).html();
    var vin = $('#vin'+$i).html();
    var location = $('#location'+$i).html();
    var price = $('#price'+$i).html();
    var photo = $('#photo'+$i).attr('src');
    window.location.href = "details.php?trans="+trans+"&&mileage="+mileage+"&&eng="+eng+"&&ext="+ext+"&&stock="+stock+"&&vin="+vin+"&&location="+location+"&&price=$$"+price+"&&photo="+photo;
  });
</script>

<?php
    include('function.php');
    $Descriptions = Descriptions();
?>
<!--vehicle1--> 
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($Descriptions);$i++){
?>

<div class="vehicle-listing alternate">
  <div class="vehicle-title-wrap"><h6><a ><?php $Descriptions[$i]['ad_title']; ?></a></h6></div>
  <div class="vehicle-inner-wrap">
     <div class="vehicle-photo" id="thumb_holder_1">
        <a ><img id="photo"+"<?php echo $i;?>" src="<?php $id=$Descriptions[$i]['id'];$Images = Images($id);  echo $Images[0]['imagepath']; ?>" class="thumbnail lazy-load" width="170px" height="140px" /></a>
     </div>
     <a >
       <div class="click-to-view"   OnClick="redirect(<?php echo $i; ?>)" ></div>
     </a>
     <div class="first-half vehicle-specs container">
        <div class="container"><span class="spec-label">Trans:</span> <span class="spec-data" id="trans"+"<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['trans']; ?></span></div>
        <div class="container"><span class="spec-label">Mileage:</span> <span class="spec-data" id="mileage"+"<?php echo $i;?>" ><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['mileage']; ?></span></div>
        <div class="container"><span class="spec-label">EXT:</span> <span class="spec-data" id="eng"+"<?php echo $i;?>" ><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['engine']; ?></span></div>
                    </div>
     <div class="second-half vehicle-specs container">
        <div class="container"><span class="spec-label">Ext Color:</span> <span class="spec-data" id="ext"+"<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['color']; ?></span></div>
        <div class="container"><span class="spec-label">Stock :</span> <span class="spec-data" id="stock"+"<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['stock']; ?></span></div>
         <div class="container"><span class="spec-label">VIN :</span> <span class="spec-data" id="vin"+"<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['vin']; ?></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="location">
         <span class="lake-worth" >Location:  <span id="location"+"<?php echo $i;?>" ><?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['state']; ?></span></span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="lake-worth">Price:  $$<span id="price"+"<?php echo $i;?>" >
  <?php echo $Descriptions[$i]['price']; ?></span></span>

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
  ?>
```

The problem is the values after redirection are undefined.
I think that the problem is in the concatenations of string (jquery or html).
for this reason the values in the redirection are false.

- Can any one please show where is the error?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: you can call `alert(var)` to check if it has the expected value. Of course stop the redirect request for the time being

Comment: The query string normally uses only one `&` to separate the get parameters. Could this be the issue?

Comment: No need to prefix javascript variables with `$`. Only PHP needs that.

Comment: do you mean in the url i have to replace `&&` by `&`, i don't think so

Comment: i replaced `$i` by `i` in the javascript part but it is the same because the declarations are the same in javascript

Comment: @The Suresh Atta : what is the problem "$$" is a string passed in the url concatenated to the value of price

Comment: only use one `&`, that part is clear cut

Comment: The problem lies here `id="trans"+"<?php echo $i;?>"` (etc). View source of your HTML page so that you can see what I mean. And you do not need `&&`.

Comment: @SalmanA: where i don't need `&&` in which part and why? and the concaténation in html with `+` or `&`

Comment: `&&mileage=` should be `&mileage=` (etc), the extra `&` does not hurt but totally unnecessary. Also you just need to do `id="trans<?php echo $i;?>"`.

Comment: @lamafif - I added the `&&` issue to my answer.

Comment: thanks everybody it is work now : the problem is in the concatenation html: the solution is like sir @SalmanA said `id="trans<?php echo $i;?>"` without `+` or `&`

Answer (score 1):

There may be other problems but with a reformat you can see you are missing a `}` before the first `</script>` tag.

also this:

```
window.location.href = "details.php?trans="+trans+"&mileage="+mileage+"&eng="+eng+"&ext="+ext+"&stock="+stock+"&vin="+vin+"&location="+location+"&price=$$"+price+"&photo="+photo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($Descriptions); $i++) {
?>

<div class="vehicle-listing alternate">
  <div class="vehicle-title-wrap">
    <h6><a >
    <?php
      echo $Descriptions[$i]['ad_title'];
```

There was no `echo`, is it the reason ?

Comment: Don't make an edit that removed a bug in the code.

Comment: No Sir, that was not me. I added this  `echo $Descriptions[$i]['ad_title'];` in place of `$Descriptions[$i]['ad_title'];`

Comment: :D It was edited three times before I edited :D But, if I did I am sorry, I will not repeat that mistake.